# Python Extension is not working in vscode bc of & command

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed python then configured it for vscode by following docs of vscode, but they said I have to right-click on the editor after seeing a run Python in terminal. And I have to click on it.
But it only works in Powershell and when I tried to use it in cmd, then they said ----

```
D:\Program\Applications\C++>& D:/Compilers-Interpreters/Python38-32/python.exe d:/Program/Applications/C++/app.py
& was unexpected at this time.

D:\Program\Applications\C++>
```

I am using the C++ folder bc I was also trying to set up C++ by following the tutorial in vscode doc. Now can someone tell me how to fix this `&` problem????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with VSCode, On the `VSCode insiders` it has been solved. You can wait for the next stable release of VSCode.

You can take this as a workaround for now:

Take adventage of `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` instead of `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows` for now.

You can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/16175) for more details.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @rafid100 Could you try this method?

Comment: Yeah it worked after next stable release Thanks :)

Comment: But they give a yellow underline if I use shell :(

Comment: @rafid100 What it prompt?

Comment: i can't send screenshot in comment so i am sending screenshot link  http://prnt.sc/165t71d this is also a famous web to send screenshot :)

Comment: @rafid100 You can just ignore it. It just encourages you to update the configuration to take 'terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows' instead of 'terminal.integrated.shell.windows'.

Comment: @rafid100 And it should be work if you have updated the VSCode to the newest version(but only accept PowerShell and Cwd).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for some reason & is being added to the beginning of your command, which makes the command invalid.

Upon testing, I actually am running into the same issue, suggesting it could be an issue with VS Code and Python. I would recommend using the debugger to run your program, which still seems to work. Just press F5 and select `Python File: Debug the currently active Python file`. Another way to do this is to define the launch.json configuration to automatically launch upon pressing F5.